# After the Noobs 1.3 OS-menu the screen goes blank

Tags: noobs

I've just installed Raspbian and Openelec with Noobs 1.3. The display I used under the installation was connected through RCA. And therefore Noobs has written two lines in the OS's config.txt files:

> hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
>
> sdtv_mode=2

The system boot's up okay, but after I choose a OS the screen goes blank. I have also tried to remove the two lines from the config-files and connect a display with a hdmi-cable, with the same result, a blank screen.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I see any OS? Everything used the work, when I used Berryboot as a method to dualboot.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the NOOBS file MD5 you downloaded matches the official MD5? Sometimes a network hiccups (really technical term'nolgy there :D) and the file might have a few bad bytes. Not enough to cause it to be seen as corrupt by a program, but enough to slightly throw off perfect execution. Worth a shot.

Comment: I just checked the sha-1 checksum of the used Noobs-zip, and it's identical to the one on the raspberry pi download-site... So that's not the problem.

Comment: This seems like an issue with Noobs 1.3. There's a thread about it here:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57032

Comment: Can you SSH in? This would allow us to see if it's a problem with your keyboard.

Comment: No I can't. As the thread I linked to describes, it seems to be a bug  that mainly affects Sandisk memorycards...

Comment: Ah, Ok. Well hopefully this helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Noobs 1.3, that mainly affects Sandisk memorycards. The solution must be to wait on an updated version of Noobs. There's a thread about it here: [raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57032](http://raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57032)